# Difference between showing items in the list or in the gallery

Tags: website-design, user-research, filter, lean-ux

I am preparing new design for filter page (something like shop page), where "items" are companies that you can choose from.
For example: You want company within UK, speaking Italian, with project costs 1-2500eur with specialty in sport industry.

[image]

Very simple example, you choose filters and the list updates. Companies are sorted by best match of your filters (if none of filters are selected, then by priority of partnership level, the most recommended by us etc.)

And now, the only things I can think of prioritizing one view style over another are

- in the gallery view you fit more examples, so the bigger database you have the better for gallery option
- List view is much clearer and let you focus at one company atm
- For RWD it's better to have gallery view as list items would take unnecessary big space (can be solved by showing 2 columns on wide screens).

Are there any clear UX rules / advantages of showing the gallery instead of the list (or vice versa)?

Thanks for all responses:)
N.

Comment: I think this comes down to how much text you want to show on the item. If you get most of the info from the thumbnail/icons, then I'd go for the gallery view. If the text is critical for the users decision to open one then I'd prefer the wider space for reading.

At the end of the day, I'd just implement a button to switch between the two for the users preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main advantage of showing it as a list is that its more easy to compare with each other. The eyes can scan the cards more easily.

Gallery option is good if you have big images of the products you want to sell. And if the images are good enough to sell the product on their own. (Tangible items for example)

I believe that in your case you would have logos of the companies that are involved. I would suggest that using a list item would be more suited for this project.

Comment: You could also do both if you want, where the user has more control of the way the result page is shown.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Ahsan's answer:

- The **gallery view** is better with highly visual content, in contexts where your users want to browse through numerous options quickly, without much details distracting them. *Think of clothing stores like Zalando, or Facebook Marketplace - the user cares primarily about how to item looks like, not what material it's made out of etc. (if so, they've already applied filters)*
- The **card view** is better for less visual content when the users wants to read details and compare the items without clicking to the full product page. This format makes the user focus more on one item at a *time, and read details that matter to them. For example, Verkkokauppa.com electronics retailer shows the main features of it. With multiple similar options, where the details matter more or as much as the looks, this is the way to go.*
  [image: Verkkokauppa.com item card]

In the end, this is something that you should find out from the users - how would they use the website, what information are they looking for and want quick access to etc.. You can (and should) already do it with just a wireframe!